# Как отправить GET запрос в nodejs

Tags: node.js

Почему не получается отправить запрос?

```
var https = require('https');
 https.request({
 hostname: 'script.google.com',  
 path: '/macros/s/AKfycbwxPZTx1yOVGmVADtbvHScQqplz49knom4t_fCTHliQx9oaN4I/exec?p=123&p_1=11&p_2=22&p_3=33&p_4=44&p_5=55'
 }, function(res) {
 console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);  
 res.on('data', function(d) {
 process.stdout.write(d);
 }
 );
 }).on('error', function(e) {
 console.error(e);
}).end();
```

Выдает

```
statusCode:  302
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?ser
vice=wise&amp;passive=1209600&amp;continue=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AK
fycbwxPZTx1yOVGmVADtbvHScQqplz49knom4t_fCTHliQx9oaN4I/exec?p%3D123%26p_1%3D11%26
p_2%3D22%26p_3%3D33%26p_4%3D44%26p_5%3D55&amp;followup=https://script.google.com
/macros/s/AKfycbwxPZTx1yOVGmVADtbvHScQqplz49knom4t_fCTHliQx9oaN4I/exec?p%3D123%2
6p_1%3D11%26p_2%3D22%26p_3%3D33%26p_4%3D44%26p_5%3D55">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: ошибка была в авторизации с гуглом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть в том, что сервер отвечает Вам редиректом. Вам следует учесть это, что если соотвествующий код-ответа есть, то следует перейти по адресу-url, что соответсвует заголовку `Location` из ответа.

```
    'use strict'

    const https = require('https');    
    let url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwxPZTx1yOVGmVADtbvHScQqplz49knom4t_fCTHliQx9oaN4I/exec?p=123&p_1=11&p_2=22&p_3=33&p_4=44&p_5=55';

    function doRequest(url) {
      https.get(url, (res) => {
        if (res.statusCode >= 300 && res.statusCode <= 400 && res.headers.location) {
          doRequest(res.headers.location);
        }
        res.on('data', (d) => {
          process.stdout.write(d);
        });

      }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
    }

    doRequest(url);
```

Comment: так тоже не срабатывает

Comment: на js все хорошо

    <script type="text/javascript">   
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwxPZTx1yOVGmVADtbvHScQqplz49knom4t_fCTHliQx9oaN4I/exec?p=123&p_1=11&p_2=22&p_3=33&p_4=44&p_5=55';  
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);   
       function gotit(data) {
       console.log(data);
       document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
      }
      </script>

Comment: @MackD Почему? Какая ошибка? У меня работает. Версия node 6.1.0

Comment: Она работает, то работает, но в таблице гугл пусто

Comment: А может быть причина из-за того что с локального компа запускаю?

Comment: @MackD Запрос сам проходит нормально. Пусто в таблице может потому, что "Документ 1Wz30DGwz26vJwie3Zy3tqudRtZuYNwIR2lJ_tKqib58 отсутствует (возможно, он был удален) (строка 3, файл logs, проект Log)" Запускать откуда угодно можно сам скрипт, можете для удобства сделать вывод в html скажем, однако я не знаю, какой ожидаемый результат должен быть после запроса, поэтому сложно понять, что именно не так.

Comment: когда просто вбиваешь в строку браузера то все добавляет или если запустить js